# Perl recognise string as scalar variable

Tags: perl

I have integer scalar variables named `$A_cine`, `$B_cine`, and so on.

I also have a subroutine `display` which takes a single argument `'A'`, `'B'`, `'C'`, etc.

I assign `$letter = $_[0]` within the subroutine. I now want to pick up the value of `$A_cine` or `$B_cine` and assign it to a new scalar variable `$cine`.

I have tried `$cine = '$'.$view."_cine"` and this recognizes `$cine` as the string `$A_cine` (which it should). However, is there a way to interpret `$A_cine` so I can get the numeric value of the scalar `$A_cine` which has been previously defined?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using symbolic references is a bad idea. Instead you should use a hash. Set up, say `%cine` and use `$cine{A}` in place of `$A_cine` etc. Then you can write

```
sub subroutine {
  my ($view) = @_;
  my $cine = $cine{$view};
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You are trying to construct a [symbolic reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Symbolic-references).

```
sub display {
    my $letter = $_[0];

    no strict 'refs';
    my $cine = ${ $letter . "_cine" };

    print $cine, "\n";  # for example
}
```

Using a hash is almost always better for this purpose. For details, see the three-part series by Mark Dominus (author of [*Higher Order Perl*](http://hop.perl.plover.com/)) on why using symbolic references can be dangerous.

- [Why it’s stupid to ‘use a variable as a variable name’](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html)
- [A More Direct Explanation of the Problem](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname2.html)
- [What if I’m Really Careful?](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname3.html)

Answer (score 4):

You can make a symbolic ref as shown above but usually it is easier to use a hash

```
%cine={}
$cine{'A'}=37;
$letter="A"
print $cine{$letter}
```