# Perl preprocessor appended to other variable

Tags: perl, preprocessor

I am trying to write following code, where I want $varPRE1 to be $var1 and $varPRE2 to be $var2 after preprocessor is evaluated, but it is not working. Is there a work around?

```
#define PRE1 1
#define PRE2 2

my $var1 = 10;
my $var2 = 20;

print $varPRE1;
print $varPRE2;
```

Comment: You almost certainly want to use some data structure other than plain scalars.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you wrote doesn't make sense even for the C preprocessor, since `varPRE1` would get parsed as one token.

What you want to do is sort of possible, using what are called symbolic references, but it is [a](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29207792/168657) [bad](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html) [idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14956232/168657).

```
$PRE1 = '1';
$PRE2 = '2';
$var1 = 10;
$var2 = 20;
print ${'var' . $PRE1};   #   same as print $var1 => 10
print ${'var' . $PRE2};
```

This will not work under `use strict refs`. It is also a bad idea to not `use strict refs`.

Comment: I would suggest this answer would benefit from an example of using a hash.